# How to add class individual items from a node list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, animation

I apologize for the title. I'm not sure how to best describe this problem in one line.

I am creating a form. This form will be validated by Regular expressions. Based on whether it's correct or not, I want to add the class `animate`, which will then trigger a CSS keyframe animation. Error will trigger a times mark, correct wil trigger a check mark.

The **issue** however. All the inputs are validated at once, resulting in all the animations triggering. I've put an event listener on each of the inputs, though I only want it running for `this` input.

In the name validator you can see the numbers from 0:3 which represent the indexes of the animations. But with a console.log I've already noticed it's sending all numbers, not just the one I want to be tied to a specific rule (Regex).

I've tried fixing it by checking the IndexOf the inputs, since their index number is the same as their cross/checkmark. But I didn't have much success. Another thing I could do is making the `animator()` a lot longer by specifically targeting the classes. But if I'd like to avoid that, since I'd like to keep the code short.

Thanks for your time :)!

You can see the snippet here:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
 background-image: url('sunset.jpg');
 background-size: 100%,100%;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.form {
 display: inline-flex;
}

input {
 margin-left: 10px;
 opacity: .8;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;


}

input[name=postalcode] {
 width: 100px;
}

.submit-btn {
   height: 41px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F8FDFF;
    top: -3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: -40px;
}

.form p {
 display: inline-table;
 color: white;
}

.fas {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fa-check {
left: -20px;
}



.slide-in-right.animate {
 -webkit-animation: slide-in-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
         animation: slide-in-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
            transform: translateX(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
            transform: translateX(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>Buttons</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="animation-library.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="form">
  <form>
   <i class="form-display fas fa-check slide-in-right" id="promotioncode"></i>
   <i class="form-error fas fa-times slide-in-right"></i>
   <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name...'><br>
   <i class="form-display fas fa-check slide-in-right"></i>
   <i class="form-error fas fa-times slide-in-right"></i>
   <input id="mail" type="text" name="email" placeholder='E-mail...'><br>
   <i class="form-display fas fa-check slide-in-right"></i>
   <i class="form-error fas fa-times slide-in-right"></i>
   <input id="phone" type="text" name="adress" placeholder='Phone...'><br>
   <i class="form-display fas fa-check slide-in-right"></i>
   <i class="form-error fas fa-times slide-in-right"></i>
   <input id="postal" type="text" name="postalcode" placeholder='Postal...'><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn">
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><p>I want spam</p>
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><p>I agree to the terms I haven't read<br>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 
 

 //Regular Expressions 
 const nameRegX = /^$/;
 const mailRegX = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 const phoneRegX = /^[0-9]{7}/;
 const postRegX = /^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}/;

 //If these are all true, form will be send
 var nameIsValid, mailIsValid, numberIsValid, postalIsValid
 nameIsValid = false;
 mailIsValid = false;
 numberIsValid = false;
 postalIsValid = false;

 

 //Eventlistener on all inpluts
 inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].onchange = function() {
     var name, mail, number, postal;
  name = inputs[0].value;
  mail = inputs[1].value;
  number = inputs[2].value;
  postal = inputs[3].value;
  
  nameValidator(name, mail, number, postal);
  }
 }



 function nameValidator(name, mail, number, postal){
  validator(!name.match(nameRegX), nameIsValid, 0)
  validator(mail.match(mailRegX), mailIsValid, 1)
  validator(number.match(phoneRegX), numberIsValid, 2)
  validator(postal.match(postRegX), postalIsValid, 3)

  if (nameIsValid, mailIsValid, numberIsValid, postalIsValid === true){
   submit(true);
  } else {
   submit(false);
  }
 }

 //Animation Selectors
 var error = document.querySelectorAll(".form-error");
 var correct = document.querySelectorAll(".form-display");

 function validator(rule, isValid, index){
   
  if (rule){
   animator(index, "correct");
   isValid = true;
  } else {
   animator(index, "error");
  }
 }

 
 
 function animator(i, validity){
  var error = document.querySelectorAll(".form-error");
  var correct = document.querySelectorAll(".form-display");
  if (validity === "error"){
   error[i].classList.add("animate")
   correct[i].classList.remove("animate")
   

  } else {
   correct[i].classList.add("animate")
   error[i].classList.remove("animate")
  }

 }
 function submit (valid){
  if (valid === false){
   return false
   console.log("don't send");
  } else {
   return true
   console.log("send");
  }
 }

 



</script>

</body>
</html>
```